# Using sed to check make sure each line only has numbers and a comma?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
0,16777215
16807368,16807368
621357328,621357328
621357403,621357403
1380962773,1380962773
1768589474,1768589474
```

Is there a way to use `sed` to make sure that each line ONLY has numbers and one comma?  If a line is missing the comma, contains letters, is blank, has spaces, etc. - then I want to delete it.

Comment: What if it has only a comma? Or numbers only on one side of comma?>

Comment: Provide a verifiable input and expected output.

Comment: It should always have one comma and at least 1 number of each side.

Comment: @123 Also, blank lines should be removed as well (since the obviously don't have commas or numbers).

Comment: @Andrew `sed '/^[0-9]\{1,\},[0-9]\{1,\}$/!d'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed -nr '/^[0-9]+,[0-9]+$/p' File
```

To edit the file in-place:

```
sed -nri '/^[0-9]+,[0-9]+$/p' File
```

A portable solution:

```
sed -nE '/^[0-9]+,[0-9]+$/p' File
```

Comment: `-r` is GNU-specific. `-E` does the same for GNU sed and also works for other seds. So use `-E` rather than `-r` for portability.

Comment: Thank Ed.. I had never really used -E before.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e '/^[0-9]\+,[0-9]\+$/ !d' file
```

The address is a regular expression. If the line does not match the regular expression, the `d` (delete) command is applied. (The exclamation mark (`!`) inverts the condition.)